# Как получить layout, в котором находится элемент в андроиде?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Вопрос по андроиду: есть кнопка, надо получить layout, в котором она находится. Как это сделать? 
Примечание: по Id нельзя, так как кнопки добавляются через inflate, и получить надо в методе onClick.

Comment: код приложите, а то не совсем понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения родителя любого `View` у него есть метод `getParent()`. Возвращаемый им результат надо скастовать из `ViewParent` к какому-либо наследнику `ViewGroup`:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) someView.getParent();
```